# Is it safe to encode and decode in c#?

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, binary, data-conversion

In c# I can encode binary data by `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` and later convert
it back by `binary = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`.

I expect that the result should be my original binary data in any case - no exception.

But is it true in any case?

Or does it depend on the specific behaviour of the `UTF8` character set?

Or should I better use `Encoding.ASCII.GetString()` and `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()`?

If anybody knows what `Encoding` exactly does (how it treats special characters or special bytes) then, please,  give me advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In c# I can encode binary data by Encoding.UTF8.GetString() and later convert it back by binary = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes().

No, because that **isn't what a text encoding does**.

A text encoding transforms arbitrary text to/from structured bytes (meaning: structured in the way defined by that encoding)

You have arbitrary bytes, not structured bytes. You should use base-64 (`Convert.ToBase64String` / `Convert.FromBase64String`), which converts arbitrary bytes to/from a structured string - in this case, structured according to the rules of base-64.

```
byte[] orig = ...
string storeThis = Convert.ToBase64String(orig);
// ...
byte[] backAgain = Convert.FromBase64String(storeThis);
```

Comment: marc, but `somestring` and `somestring2` here should be always same right? since I first convert it to `UTF8`? `string somestring = ...;
            string somestring2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(somestring));`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes, but that is a **different example**. That is not what the question describes. What the question describes is: `byte[] somebytes = ...; byte somebytes2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(somebytes));` - and that is **not** going to work

Comment: I just cross checked whether my understanding is correct or not, I know my question is different than what OP asked. Thanks Marc

Answer (score 1):

You should only use the Encoding.UTF8, when you expect the bytes are in UTF8 encoding. Using the GetString() on *unknown* bytes can lead to **unexpected** results.

So if you use Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello world!"); You can bring it back to a string with Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);