# base64string to string back to base64string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying an experiment to convert a base64string to a string then back to a base64string, however, I am not getting my original base64string:

```
String profilepic = "/9j/4AAQ";

string Orig = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(profilepic));

string New = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Orig));
```

The string **New** returns "/f//4AAQ".

Any thoughts of why this is happening?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/19025587/2530848

Comment: What is in the base64 encoded string 'profilepic'? Arbitrary bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You should do it as below:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Text;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string profilepic = "/9j/4AAQ";
            string New = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(profilepic));
            byte[] raw = Convert.FromBase64String(New); // unpack the base-64 to a blob
            string s = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(raw); // outputs /9j/4AAQ
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming that the base64-encoded binary data in your example contains a UTF-16 encoded message. This may simply not be the case, and the `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode` class may alter the contents by discarding the bytes that it doesn't understand.

Therefore, the result of base64-encoding the UTF-16 encoded byte stream of the returned string may not yield the same output.

Your input string contains the binary sequence 0xff 0xd8 0xff 0xe0 0x00 0x10 (in hex). Interpreting this as UTF-16LE (which you're using with `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode`) the first character would be 0xffd8, but is placed in the string as 0xfffd, which explains the change.

I tried decoding it with `Encoding.Unicode`, `Encoding.UTF8` and `Encoding.Default`, but none of them yielded anything intelligible.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I'll remember to keep this in mind next time I'm messing with the different encoding.